# Laravel One to Many Relation issue

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I have a users table and consultant_profile table set up on my db. They are related and in my controller action i can see in the users object(from a model) that it has a relations array and in there is the profile object.

I am now trying to create a table for qualifications which has a one to many relationship with the consultants profile so one profile can have many qualifications.

For ease i here is a shorter version of the schema for the tables:

```
consultant_profile [
    - id
    - address line 1
    - postcode
]

consultant_qualifications [
    - id
    - consultant_profile_id
    - qualification
]
```

I have put this in my model for the consultant_profile

```
public function qualifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ConsultantQualifications', 'consultant_profile_id');
}
```

and this in my consultant_qualifications model

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ConsultantProfile',null,"consultant_profile_id");
}
```

I have tried it with putting in foreign/local keys and without.

What i expect the out come to be is i can look in the relations array of user object and see the profile object, i could then look into profile object and in its relations array i should see qualifications object

But i don't, any reason why?

Comment: Get rid of that `null`. Foreign key is 2nd param in both `hasMany` and `belongsTo`, so `consultant_profile_id` goes there, that's all.

Comment: Hi Jared.  Yeah I've already tried that I've tried many combinations

Comment: So rephrase your question, add error or actual result and what you expect instead.

Comment: I have got actual result and expected result in there already mate, the last paragraph and sentence

Comment: First of all, there is no actual result at all. Secondly, show the code you'd like to get, not `I'd like to see X and look into Y` - it's not precise.